# Why my Masking Policy With Javascript UDF is not working with aggregate function in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a making policy in snowflake which calls UDF when the condition fails.

UDF :

```
create or replace function "ANKET_DB".PUBLIC.ThrowColumnAccessException(column_name string) returns string language javascript as 
$$ 
msg = 'ERROR: User is not authorized for ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' column in this query.'; 
throw msg; 
$$;
```

Masking Policy:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE MASKING POLICY
    "ANKET_DB"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES_MASKING_P"
    AS (VAL amount)
    RETURNS number -> CASE when like(CURRENT_AVAILABLE_ROLES(), '%PREV_USER_UBAKA%') then ANKET_DB.PUBLIC.ThrowColumnAccessException('AMOUNT')
    ELSE VAL END

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "ANKET_DB"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES" MODIFY COLUMN "AMOUNT" SET MASKING POLICY "ANKET_DB"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES_MASKING_P"
```

Query :

```
select AMOUNT FROM "ANKET_DB"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"; - WORKS

select SUM(AMOUNT) FROM "ANKET_DB"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"; -DOESNT WORK (SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300010:2596942238; incident 2830675.)
```

Note: The Amount Column is of NUMBER datatype

Is there any workaround to achieve the same?

Comment: I do not recommend throwing an error from a JavaScript UDF as a masking policy. You should simply return a varchar through SQL with the same message.

Comment: You can format your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I wonder how the first query works! according to snowflake documentation : Currently, Snowflake does not support different input and output data types in a masking policy. and your masking function is returning string while Val is number in your masking policy.

Comment: @eshirvana [link] (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction.html#type-conversion-within-javascript) states that it automatically handles type conversion if I understood it right.

Comment: @GregPavlik It's a requirement. An exception is expected instead of showing random data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to explicitly pass the datatype in the aggregate function, then it works fine.

Solution:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT::NUMBER) 
FROM "ANKET_DB"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES"."CUSTOMER_SERVICES";
```